# Wordpress post prev/next arrow replace I.E. rel="next">«</a> - searched high and low and can't find the code?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, navigation

Running a plugin called WP Single Post Navigation, I've customized the styling of the previous/next arrows however I would like to replace the "«" with a "<"...seems simple enough, and the code appears in the Inspect Element window in a div, however after looking through every conceivable file via ftp: plugin folder, wordpress folder, theme folder, etc. for this line of code, I just can't find it?!? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

What's weird is that it's calling from what appears to be a plugin folder file but I checked them all and nothing of the sort appears in any of them, css or php:

```
<div id="wpspn-nextpost" title="Next post: name"> <a href="link/"
> rel="next">«</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt many people on here have that plugin to go searching in. So, if you have Jquery loaded just do this $("#wpspn-nextpost a").text("<"); ?

Answer (score 0):

After more delving I discovered, as it's described in Wordpress codex "fun character entities" the following:

`&raquo;     »     double right angle quote
&laquo;     «      double left angle quote
&lt;     <      single left arrow (left angle bracket)
&gt;     >      single right arrow (right angle bracket)`

And voila! replaced: `

```
function wpspn_previous_post_link() {$args = array (
    'format'            => '%link',     // Link format (default: %link)
    'link'                  => '&gt;',   // Link string (default: &raquo;)
    'in_same_cat'           => FALSE,       // Apply only to same category (default: FALSE)
    'excluded_categories'   => ''           // Exclude categories (default: empty)
);
```

`